# VBA Excel "error 13: type mismatch"

Tags: vba, excel, random

I used this code to create 100000 numbers (12 digit unique random numeric numbers )

```
Sub uniqueramdom()

Const strCharacters As String = "0123456789"

Dim cllAlphaNums As Collection
Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 60000) As String
Dim varElement As Variant
Dim strAlphaNum As String
Dim AlphaNumIndex As Long
Dim lUbound As Long
Dim lNumChars As Long
Dim i As Long

Set cllAlphaNums = New Collection
lUbound = UBound(arrUnqAlphaNums)
lNumChars = Len(strCharacters)

On Error Resume Next
Do
    strAlphaNum = vbNullString
    For i = 1 To 12
        strAlphaNum = strAlphaNum & Mid(strCharacters, Int(Rnd() * lNumChars) + 1, 1)
    Next i
    cllAlphaNums.Add strAlphaNum, strAlphaNum
Loop While cllAlphaNums.Count < lUbound
On Error GoTo 0

For Each varElement In cllAlphaNums
    AlphaNumIndex = AlphaNumIndex + 1
    arrUnqAlphaNums(AlphaNumIndex) = varElement
Next varElement

Range("A1").Resize(lUbound).Value = Application.Transpose(arrUnqAlphaNums)

Set cllAlphaNums = Nothing
Erase arrUnqAlphaNums

End Sub
```

It works with:     `Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 50000) As String`

But with:     `Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 100000) As String` , it not working and producing Error : type mismatch

I have the following code in here [http://www.excelforum.com/](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/942022-how-to-generate-16-digit-unique-random-alpha-numeric-numbers-print.html)

Comment: @Jeeped Here is the Error `Range("A1").Resize(lUbound).Value = Application.Transpose(arrUnqAlphaNums)`

Comment: the code still work good but i want to create 100000 numbers, but this code just create 60000 (Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 60000) As String), if create 100000 numbers (Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 100000) As String) it error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have hit the limitation of Transpose. the below would work

```
Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 65536 ) As String 'remember the number 65536?
```

this wont work

```
Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 65537 ) As String
```

You will find that this limitation inherited on ranges from prior versions of Excel. Microsoft may have left some business incomplete

you could probably refactor the code as below

```
Option Explicit
Sub uniqueramdom()

    Const strCharacters As String = "0123456789"

    Dim strAlphaNum As String
    Dim AlphaNumIndex As Long
    Dim lUbound As Long
    Dim lNumChars As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 1

    lUbound = 100000 'Change here your ubound. This can increase execution time.
    lNumChars = Len(strCharacters)

    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        strAlphaNum = vbNullString
        For i = 1 To 12
            strAlphaNum = strAlphaNum & Mid(strCharacters, Int(Rnd() * lNumChars) + 1, 1)
        Next i
        Cells(iRow, 1) = strAlphaNum
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop While iRow <= lUbound
    On Error GoTo 0


End Sub
```

Comment: That is great MR.Krishna. Good..!

Comment: Format A1:A100000 as Text before running the routine and you will not lose leading zeroes when Excel converts the numbers-as-text to numbers on-the-fly.

Comment: The claim that _you have hit the limitation of Range_ is wrong.  The error is due to a limitation of the `Transpose` method (as Japeed identified). The work around to write to 100,000 cells individually is grossly inefficient.  The simplest answer is to stuff the results into a 2D array as you generate them and move that to the range without the transpose.

Comment: thanks @chrisneilsen, i learned something new. +1 and +1 for jeeped already.

Answer (score 3):

You were running into an old functional size limitation of `application.transpose`. If you move to a 2-D array and fill the proper rank, you should not require the use of transpose at all.

```
Sub uniqueramdom()

    Const strCharacters As String = "0123456789"

    Dim cllAlphaNums As Collection
    Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 100000, 1 To 1) As String
    Dim varElement As Variant
    Dim strAlphaNum As String
    Dim AlphaNumIndex As Long
    Dim lUbound As Long
    Dim lNumChars As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set cllAlphaNums = New Collection
    lUbound = UBound(arrUnqAlphaNums, 1)
    lNumChars = Len(strCharacters)

    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        strAlphaNum = vbNullString
        For i = 1 To 12
            strAlphaNum = strAlphaNum & Mid(strCharacters, Int(Rnd() * lNumChars) + 1, 1)
        Next i
        cllAlphaNums.Add strAlphaNum, strAlphaNum
    Loop While cllAlphaNums.Count < lUbound
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each varElement In cllAlphaNums
        AlphaNumIndex = AlphaNumIndex + 1
        arrUnqAlphaNums(AlphaNumIndex, 1) = varElement
    Next varElement

    Range("A1").Resize(lUbound) = arrUnqAlphaNums

    Set cllAlphaNums = Nothing
    Erase arrUnqAlphaNums

End Sub
```