# get entire row of array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, rows

I have the following code below,

I want to get the entire row not just column 1 of the original array, how would i do this?

```
Sub Example1()
    Dim arrValues() As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim filteredArray()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim tempArray()

    lastRow = Sheets("Raw Data").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Raw Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    arrValues = Sheets("Raw Data").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 21)).Value

    ' First use a temporary array with just one dimension
    ReDim tempArray(1 To UBound(arrValues))
    For lCount = 1 To UBound(arrValues)
        If arrValues(lCount, 3) = "phone" Then
            lRow = lRow + 1
            tempArray(lRow) = arrValues(lCount, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Now we know how large the filteredArray needs to be: copy the found values into it
    ReDim filteredArray(1 To lRow, 1 To 1)
    For lCount = 1 To lRow
        filteredArray(lCount, 1) = tempArray(lCount)
    Next

    Sheets("L").Range("A2:U" & 1 + lRow) = filteredArray
End Sub
```

Comment: `= application.Transpose(filteredArray)` should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ReDim statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) can add records on-the-fly with the **PRESERVE** parameter but only into the last rank. This is a problem as the second rank of a two dimensioned array is typically considered the 'columns' while the first are the 'rows'.

The `Application.Transpose` can flip rows into columns and vise-versa but it has limitations. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451126/error13-in-excel-vba-in-data-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400105/vba-excel-error-13-type-mismatch))

A simple function to transpose without these limitations is actually very easy to build. All you really need are two arrays and two nested loops to flip them.

```
Sub Example1()
    Dim arrVALs() As Variant, arrPHONs() As Variant
    Dim v As Long, w As Long

    With Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 21).Offset(1, 0)
            arrVALs = .Cells.Value
            'array dimension check
            'Debug.Print LBound(arrVALs, 1) & ":" & UBound(arrVALs, 1)
            'Debug.Print LBound(arrVALs, 2) & ":" & UBound(arrVALs, 2)
            'Debug.Print Application.CountIf(.Columns(3), "phone") & " phones"
        End With
    End With

    ReDim arrPHONs(1 To UBound(arrVALs, 2), 1 To 1)
    For v = LBound(arrVALs, 1) To UBound(arrVALs, 1)
        If LCase(arrVALs(v, 3)) = "phone" Then
            For w = LBound(arrVALs, 2) To UBound(arrVALs, 2)
                arrPHONs(w, UBound(arrPHONs, 2)) = arrVALs(v, w)
            Next w
            ReDim Preserve arrPHONs(1 To UBound(arrPHONs, 1), _
                                    1 To UBound(arrPHONs, 2) + 1)
        End If
    Next v

    'there is 1 too many in the filtered array
    ReDim Preserve arrPHONs(1 To UBound(arrPHONs, 1), _
                            1 To UBound(arrPHONs, 2) - 1)

    'array dimension check
    'Debug.Print LBound(arrPHONs, 1) & ":" & UBound(arrPHONs, 1)
    'Debug.Print LBound(arrPHONs, 2) & ":" & UBound(arrPHONs, 2)

    'Option 1: use built-in Transpose
    'Worksheets("L").Range("A2:U" & UBound(arrPHONs, 2) + 1) = Application.Transpose(arrPHONs)

    'Option 2: use custom my_2D_Transpose
    Worksheets("L").Range("A2:U" & UBound(arrPHONs, 2) + 1) = my_2D_Transpose(arrPHONs)

End Sub

Function my_2D_Transpose(arr As Variant)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, tmp() As Variant
    ReDim tmp(1 To UBound(arr, 2), 1 To UBound(arr, 1))
    For a = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For b = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            tmp(b, a) = Trim(arr(a, b))
        Next b
    Next a
    my_2D_Transpose = tmp
End Function
```

So if you are in a hurry and the scope of your arrays is such that you will never reach the limits of `Application.Transpose` then by all means use it. If you cannot safely use transpose then use a custom function.

Comment: This Function and routine works great for some reason the date in the first column seems to change its format in the process..the original raw data is 05/11/2015 however it ends up on Sheet("L" as 11/05/2015

Comment: VBA is very US-EN centric. I would advise changing to `arrVALs = .Cells.Value2` and using the worksheet's cell formatting to achieve your DMY date formats. 05-Nov-2015 will show up as 42,313 until you format it.