# Array into worksheet - Type Mismatch

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, transpose

I am trying to unload an array into a worksheet. This code works with no errors, but it creates three rows and many columns (as I would expect):

```
Dim ToKeepArray() As Variant
ReDim ToKeepArray(1 To 3, 1 To LastRow) As Variant
'Populate the Array (this part works fine)

Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = Sheets("TO_KEEP").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1))

TargetRange.Resize(UBound(ToKeepArray, 1), UBound(ToKeepArray, 2)).Value = ToKeepArray
```

However, if I try to transpose the whole thing by using:

```
TargetRange.Resize(UBound(ToKeepArray, 2), UBound(ToKeepArray, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(ToKeepArray)
```

I get a `Type Mismatch` error; same if I drop the `.value`.

I know how to loop through the array (so I could find a workaround for what I am trying to do) but what am I missing, why am I getting that error? What is mismatched...?

Comment: How big is the array?  Transpose has a limit to the number of items it will accept.

Comment: @ScottCraner: The array has just over 3 x 250 elements, but this is a fair point, since I expect this to go well beyond 100.000 when deployed

Comment: Then look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589463/get-entire-row-of-array/33589875#33589875).  @Jeeped gave a great answer with a custom function to flip it.

Comment: @ScottCraner: was no aware of those limitations, thanks a lot for pointing that out! However, the test I am using is definitely not that large. Could there be another cause...?

Comment: Do you have any long text values in the array? (longer than 255 characters)

Comment: @Rory: yes, I do; does that impact the Transpose, or is it a wider issue ?

Comment: Yes, it will cause `Transpose` a problem. You'll need to loop.

Comment: Very good to know about both these limitations; who will post the answer now? :)